# Cant load protobuf message with protobuf.js

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

Im trying to use proto messages with protobuf.js, encode them and send them to a RabbitMQ message broker. I have the following sub-folders inside my project:

```
- model
    - protos
        - transactions.proto
    - RabitMQ.js
- routes
    - rmq-api.js
```

I added a route which does the following(Using express) in the rmq-api.js file:

```js
const RabbitMQ = require('../model/RabbitMQ');

router.post('/api/transactions' ,function (req,res,next) {
    RabbitMQ.PublishTransactionsMessage(DummyMessage).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send({message: "OK :)"});
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send({error:e.message});
    });
});
```

In the RabitMQ.js file I have the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
    PublishTransactionsMessage: function(message) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            amqp.connect(RabbitMQConfig.url, function (error, connection) {
                if (error) {
                    console.error("Could not connect to the rabbit message broker on {0} - " +
                        "Check connection please and try again".format(RabbitMQConfig.url));
                    console.error("Error message - {0}".format(error));
                    reject(error)
                }
                connection.createChannel(function(error, channel) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error("Could Create channel - {0}".format(error.message));
                        reject(error)
                    }
                    const queue = RabbitMQConfig.queue;
                    channel.assertQueue(queue, {
                        durable: true
                    });
                    // Convert Message to protobuff
                    protobuf.load("./protos/transactions.proto").then((err, root) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        let ScraperMessageResult = root.lookupType("transactions.ScraperMessageResult");
                        const errMsg = ScraperMessageResult.verify(message);
                        if (errMsg)
                            reject(errMsg);
                        let buffer = ScraperMessageResult.encode(message).finish();
                        channel.sendToQueue(queue, buffer);
                        console.log(`Sent ${message} to queue: ${queue}`);
                        resolve()
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
};
```

In the code shown above in the line:
`protobuf.load("./protos/transactions.proto").then((err, root) => {`
I keep catching the following error:
[image]

Inside this catch block:

```
  }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
  });
```

This seems like a pretty simple problem however I havent found anything on this online so I might be missing something really simple here.
P.S. I tried using __dirname + "/protos/transaction.proto" and still couldnt get this to work.
Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Did you found the solution? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function doesn't look at the dist directory,

```
await protocolBuffer.load(__dirname + '/item.proto'); should look there,
```

and also you need to copy the file manuly by using copy/cp command, you can add it as part of the package json script like so:

```
 "build": "nest build && COPY src\\reading_list\\protocol_buffer\\*.proto dist\\reading_list\\protocol_buffer\\"
```